# How many ways are there to assign three different jobs to five different employees if each employee can be given more than one job?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The answer is that the first job can be assigned to 5 different employees, the same with the second and the third jobs, so the answer is $ 5^3 $.

My first thought was to create the equation $ x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 3 $ so that each of the $x$'s  represents a worker and their, values the number of jobs given to each. The number of solutions of the equation $  {{7} \choose{3}}  = 35 $. Can anyone help me see what is wrong with this reasoning?

Comment: The equation does not distinguish between worker 1 gets job A and 2 gets B, and worker 1 gets job B and 2 gets A.

Answer (score 2):

The equation only gives the number of ways that identical jobs could be assigned, but if the jobs are different it doesn't work. Number of ways to choose 3 workers to do 3 jobs is 10, and with 3 different jobs this is 10 * 3! = 60 ways to allocate. Number of ways to choose a worker to do 2 and a worker to do 1 is 5 * 4 = 20, and there are 3 ways to arrange the jobs, so this is another 20 * 3 = 60 ways to allocate. There are 5 ways to give all 3 jobs to 1 worker. Total ways is 60 + 60 + 5 = 125, agreeing with the answer. The equation method only gives 10 + 20 + 5 = 35.

Comment: It took me some time to understand this other way you use to calculate the answer. It really makes it clearer. Thank you!